# Suggested dd-wrt security settings for home network?

Tags: security, router, dd-wrt

So for I am using WPA2 Home with AES, with MAC address filtering.

Any other suggestions?

**Update**

I am not broadcasting my ssid either.

Comment: Not broadcasting your SSID [isn't a good idea after all](https://dfarq.homeip.net/why-hiding-your-ssid-makes-your-security-worse/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really wanted more security, you could switch off SSID broadcasting and only let specific wireless cards connect (defined by MAC address).

Comment: thanks, I forgot to mention I am not broadcasting either!

Answer (score 1):

- Disable telnet and http - only allow SSH (private keys set) and https.
- Change key renewal interval from 3600 seconds to 1800 seconds (or less?)
- Lower the TX power - you don't want your wireless to be sniffed from outside your property

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend restricting access to your AP (remote login) to wired only, mac address filtering, and use WPA2 changing your wireless password quite often.